# Google My Maps: How can I export coordinates from a network-linked KML file?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

I've been checking out the documentation for Google's "My Maps" service, and I can't figure out if it will let me do what I need to do.

Our client has a map, created using My Maps, that defines several delivery areas using colored polygons. I understand that it's possible to export a KML file containing the coordinates for these polygons, and that it's also possible to create a network link so said KML file will be updated whenever the map is.

My problem: I don't know what to actually do with the KML file. I need some sort of script that can take the network-linked KML, and return a human-readable set of coordinates that I can use to define delivery areas on the client's site. **In other words, they need to be able to edit or create delivery zones on this map, then on their site, bind each polygon to a particular store to determine which store must deliver which orders.** There's a lot of complicated stuff going on here, but for this first step I just need to know how to get the coordinates for the separate shapes in a reliable way.

I wish I had some code to post to make this a more useful post, but it's more a question of whether or not this type of functionality is actually possible. Please help me figure this out!

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html)?

Comment: @geocodezip Pretty much exactly like that, yeah - as long as this example is getting the info from a KML file. How might I accomplish something like this?

Comment: That example is getting the polygons from a [KML file](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/TrashDays40.xml), to see how it works, view the source of the page, it uses a third party KML parser, [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

Answer (score 1):

The KML file is a XML file then  you can inspect the file both server side with a XML parser or client side via JQuery.

this is an essential javascript sample for a client side approch:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", filename, false); // filename = kml_filename

 xmlDocObj = $($.parseXML(request.responseText));  

 var placemarks = xmlDocObj.find("Placemark");
 placemarks.each(function (index) {

 ... your parsing for the geometry object and coordinates content you need

}
```